# Docker Swarm - Map ports and Scaling

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am currently using Docker Engine 1.11, and I am investigating if its possible for me to move to Docker 1.12 and use Swarm. I am currently using Docker to run 50+ Bamboo agents, all of which need to have a port mapped to a port on the server. For instance, each docker container needs to have port 4000 available, so when I do Docker run, I do-

```
Docker run -p 10000:4000 myimg
Docker run -p 10001:4000 myimg
Docker run -p 10002:4000 myimg
Docker run -p 10003:4000 myimg
```

In Docker Swarm, from what I understand, I would run the following command to scale my service to 50 containers

```
docker service scale helloworld=5
```

But, if I did this, then they would all be trying to map to the same port. How can I accomplish this? Is it possible?

Comment: Note that you can upgrade to 1.12 while continuing to use Docker as you have in 1.11, without using the new Swarm mode features. If you have some services that can use the new Swarm mode, they can then run on the same servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

It's just one key function that docker service provides that a single port can map to multi containers(service discovery)

And another one is when container fails, swarm will start a new one.(self healing)

I know nothing about Bamboo, so I can't tell you if there's a way to run bamboo service with the swarm mode.

Comment: It's actually a database in the container that needs the port available. Thanks for the reply! Hopefully this feature will come out. It would be nice to just scale the port mapped up by one for each instance or something.